# Replacing strings in filenames with exclamation marks and ampersand using batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-rename

I'm trying to replace strings in filenames using a batch script but run into problems if the files have  exclamation marks or ampersand.

```
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Set "Pattern=[String_A]"
Set "Replace=[B_String]"
For %%a in (*.*) Do (
    Set "File=%%~a"
    Ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!"
)
```

The code above works for filenames without those but I need help for the rest.

This is something I have to run multiple times (it's part of bigger script).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the expansion in `set "file=%%~a` will be only safe, if delayed expansion is disabled.
The solution is toggling the delayed expansion mode.

```
Setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "Pattern=[String_A]"
Set "Replace=[B_String]"
For %%a in (*.*) Do (
    Set "File=%%~a"
    Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Ren "!file!" "!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!"
    endlocal
)
```

Comment: I thought I tried this but must have swap things. Thank you!